What purpose is the GND screw serving in this vanity lighting setup?
Trying to install a bathroom vanity light. Here's the wiring coming out of the wall:

So 3 wires:

White
Black
Bare copper
Plus a green GND screw

This wiring was set up by our electrician before we were ready to decide on a final vanity.
Here is the vanity:

So, again, 3 wires:

White
Black
Bare copper/metal

Common sense would say I need to just join white:white, black:black, bare:bare, but I'm concerned about the green GND screw not being utilized with that strategy.
Do I need to tie the bare metal wires (either one, or both) into the GND screw or do I just leave it alone? Much more importantly: why or why not?

Plus a green GND screw ... how is that a description of a wire?

I mean if a wire's job is to connect thing and a screw's job is to connect thing then they're basically one in the same

One quick recommendation: Your pictures do not show the green screw, as best as I can see. Though it's quite true most experts will be able to say what to do with the green screw without seeing it, it's possible others may not know, so showing it in the pictures may help others know what you're talking about.

Why is the bkack wire taped back?

The green screw is to make sure the metal box/pieces are also grounded.
Usually loop some of the wire around it and tighten the screw.  Then connect the two bare wires wires together

Thanks (and +1). To confirm: I wrap the thinner bare wire of the light fixture around the green screw a few times, tighten the green screw down, and then (with the remaining excess) wingnut the two bare wires together?

@IamYourFaja   Just make a half loop with the house bare wire.  This is so the box stays grounded if you remove the light fixture.

@crip659 what's a half loop—just a tight U shape?

@Huesmann   Yes.  Most electrical screws are made for a single wire/single layer.  A half loop/U-shape gives the best area coverage/connection at the proper torque.  The U end can touch, but should not cross over itself.
